# Build failed with exception while using react-native-vectoricons

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

Here is the error while using react-native-vectorIcons. I have followed the instruction on https://github.com/oblador/react-native-vector-icons but still faced error while building project.

[image: VectorIcons]

here is the code of MainActivity.java

```
protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
        return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
            new MainReactPackage(),
            new VectorIconsPackage(),
            new MapsPackage(this)
        );
    }
```

here is the code of settings.gradle

```
include ':app', ':react-native-maps'
project(':react-native-maps').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-maps/android')
include ':react-native-vector-icons'
project(':react-native-vector-icons').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-vector-icons/android')
```

can anybody tell me what is the problem?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which version of react-native you are using?

Comment: i am using react-native 0.28.0 You can check my solution.

Answer (score 0):

Please just do `react-native run-android --debug` once .. Hope it helps you.

Comment: your solution doesn't work but still i found out the way you can have a look at my answer. and thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

hey guys error was due to some missing line in build.gradle file i fixed it and everything is working fine now
here is the line which was missing

```
dependencies {
    .....
    compile project(':react-native-vector-icons')
}
```

also the problem was i installed react-native-vector-icons of version 1.10.3 please update it to 2.0.3 by using

```
npm install --save react-native-vector-icons@2.0.3
```

that's all you are done. Queries and doubt are welcome